# Change value of JavaScript in inspector web browser

Tags: javascript, networking

Is it possible to change a javascript value within the browser inspector?.

I need to change it from the browser since I cannot change those values in the router from ssh since the partitions are in read-only mode.

It would be to change the value marked by 'yes'.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What you're attempting won't work; it might look like you've 'hacked the system' and evaded a permission restriction, but it'll still get caught by a check function later on. All you're doing is changing the client-side behaviour, everything server-side is the same and will still disallow the operation.

Answer (score 0):

Open the Console by clicking `f12` and selecting the console tab, and then try to write:

`document.dlna_form.samba_active.value = "Yes";`

check if it even works by writing:

`document.dlna_form.samba_active.value;`

if not, then try to find it's ID and then write:

`document.getElementById('the_ID').value = "Yes";`

when your done just write:

`document.dlna_form.samba_active.value;`

to see if it has changed.

FYI: if the server has some other validation on the server side then what your doing will not work, you can try some other methods by sending requests of GET or POST with different input data based on the server that your trying to change.